# Empty XFCE Applications menu

Tags: xfce, menu

After installing one application that put its launcher in the wrong menu category I decided to relocate it to its correct category. To this effect I edited the Applications menu (`right click on it -> Properties -> Edit menu`). After making little changes to the menu its entries disappeared and now looks like shown in the following image:

[image: No entries in the main XFCE menu]

I have looked at the instructions in the [XFCE Wiki](http://xfce.wikia.com/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_to_edit_the_auto_generated_menu_with_the_menu_editor.3F) and I'm supposed to do:

```
# cp ~/.cache/xfce4/desktop/menu-cache-name-of-the-generated-file.xml ~/.config/xfce4/desktop/menu2.xml
# cd ~/.config/xfce4/desktop/
# cat menu.xml > menu3.xml
# cat menu2.xml >> menu3.xml
# mv menu.xml menu.orig.xml
# mv menu3.xml menu.xml
```

but there's no `~/.cache/xfce4/desktop/` directory in my computer.

What can I do to restore the main applications menu?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Merkat with XFCE.

Comment: does [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/XubuntuPanels) help?  if yes, I'l post it as an answer

Comment: OK, I read that information but deals with lost panels and main menu. In my case the main XFCE menu is there but without any child elements (entries).

Answer (score 3):

This should restore the menu to your panel:

1. Right Click on your panel
2. Select Add New items from the pull up list
3. Scroll down to the bottom of the resultant dialog
4. Click on Xfce Menu
5. Click on the Add Button

and, as per the link provided by Philomath, you can elect to change the title to "Applications."

Comment: The problem is that I do have the Applications menu, but with no entries. Even if I add a new one, it behaves the same. :-(

Comment: Please edit your post to reflect the true nature of your issue. You can always manually edit the menu like so: http://xubuntu.wordpress.com/2006/07/12/manually-edit-the-xfce-menu/

Answer (score 3):

I finally found a solution by myself. Reading here and there I found some promessing xml files in the `/etc/xdg/menus` directory. From there I copied the `xfce-applications.menu` file to `~/.config/xfce4/desktop/menu.xml` and edited the main application menu in my desktop to take its entries from that file (`right clicked on the main menu -> Properties -> Use custom menu file`). Everything came back to normal.

I would like to thank everybody (specially those who provided some hints) for their help.

Comment: I found that deleting/renaming `~/.config/menus/xfce-applications.menu` will fix the problem also