# Where can I find a canonical list of categories for desktop files in XFCE?

Tags: xfce

I am running Debian 9 (stretch) and XFCE.  I am creating a desktop file so I can launch [Mozilla Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/) from the Whisker menu. I would like Thunderbird to have the right value for its `Categories` attribute.  I generated a list of categories using the following command. An example of the command's output also follows.

```
cd /usr/share/applications
grep -i -P -e "^[Cc]ategories[=].*" ./*.desktop | sort | uniq
```

**List of Categories**
[image]

However, the list I generated might not be complete.  I have read other questions including:

- [How do I create an Xfce application menu containing only the contents
  of one category?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253763/how-do-i-create-an-xfce-application-menu-containing-only-the-contents-of-one-cat)
- [Add icons/menu items for applications in XFCE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/480728/add-icons-menu-items-for-applications-in-xfce)
- [Empty XFCE Applications menu](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16918/empty-xfce-applications-menu)

Where can I find a complete and canonical list of categories?

Here is the desktop file I created.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Thunderbird
GenericName=Thunderbird mail client
Comment=Check email using a local Thunderbird mail client
Exec=/opt/thunderbird/thunderbird %F
Icon=/home/username/Pictures/Icons/thunderbird-256.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Network;Office;Email;
MimeType=message/rfc822;message/x-gnu-rmail;
X-XFCE-MimeType=x-scheme-handler/mailto;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

freedesktop.org maintains a lot of the xdg standards, including categories.

https://standards.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/latest/apa.html

Email is an additional category that can be used with the Network or Office category. Some of the additional categories should be used with one of the main categories. Others can be used with any of them.

Whether this is well enforced or merely a suggestion, I don't know.